# Dynamically calling array value by index number

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having trouble calling the values of an array using their index number dynamically.
What I'm trying to do is get the name of a movieclip dynamically each time the for loop calls. 
My code:

```
public var allItemsUnlockedTC:Array = new Array("Itemwrench", "Itemsc", "Itemvoltmeter", "Itemgloves", "Itemstirespray");

for(var TCitems:int = 0; TCitems < allItemsUnlockedTC.length; TCitems++)
            {
                trace("TCitems length: " + TCitems);
                trace("Values: " + allItemsUnlockedTC.valueOf([TCitems]));
                /*getChildByName(allItemsUnlockedTC.valueOf(TCitems) as MovieClip).x = par.toolCloset.kast_1.slotTC1;//getChildByName("slotTC" + (TCitems + 1)).x + 400;
                getChildByName(allItemsUnlockedTC.valueOf(TCitems) as MovieClip).y = par.toolCloset.kast_1.slotTC1;//getChildByName("slotTC" + (TCitems + 1)).y + 245;
                getChildByName(allItemsUnlockedTC.valueOf(TCitems) as MovieClip).gotoAndStop(2);
                //getChildByName(allItemsUnlockedTC.valueOf(TCitems)).name = ("slotTC" + (TCitems + 1));
                NotinventoryParentTC.addChild(getChildByName(allItemsUnlockedTC.valueOf(TCitems) as MovieClip));*/
            }
```

Instead of getting the values one by one in ascending order, I get all values at once every time the for loop calls.

How do I call the value by the index using the for loop ?

Thanks in advance,

Milan

Nevermind, I solved it.

```
trace("Values: " + allItemsUnlockedTC[TCitems]);
```

Stupid question xS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get the item at the specific index. In actionscript this is done like this: `yourArray[index]`. Don't use `valueOf`.

so it would look like:

```
trace("Values: " + allItemsUnlockedTC[TCitems]);
```

Comment: I figured it out before your answer but it was the right answer you supplied. Just need to remove the period though :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `for each...in` loop.

```
 for each(var TCitems:String in allItemsUnlockedTC)
 {
            trace("TCitems length: " + allItemsUnlocked.indexOf(TCitems));
            trace("Values: " + TCitems);
 }
```

Note that this was just off the top of my head and the code may not be entirely correct.

Comment: The code you supplied doesn't work in my case. But I already fixed the problem.